# vlookup but the name of the cell that will return not the value in the cell

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

just like to ask if you know a formula like in the vlookup style but the cell name that it will return not the value of the cell? thanks!

I want to put the value of `sal` in the `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(name, Sheet2.Range("Table6"), 5, False)` but in this function the value inside the cell will return not the name of the cell

```
Sub purchase()

Dim name As String
name = ActiveSheet.Range("C3")
sal = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(name, Sheet2.Range("Table6"), 5, False) - ActiveSheet.Range("d3").Value

MsgBox " remaining: " & sal   

End Sub
```

Comment: So you want the **address** of the cell?  Or the **range name** associated with the cell?  And how do you then intend to subtract something from that address or name?

Comment: Would `MATCH()` function give you the result you need?

Answer (score 0):

`VLookup` only returns a value. You will need the `match` function. This will return the row number which you can use to access the desired cells.

```
Sub purchase()
    Dim Name As String
    Name = ActiveSheet.Range("C3")

    Dim MatchedRow As Long
    MatchedRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Name, Sheet2.Range("Table6").Columns(1), 0)
      'Find the row number (relative to the range table6) of the found name

    Dim Sal As Double
    Sal = Sheet2.Range("Table6").Cells(MatchedRow, 5).Value - ActiveSheet.Range("D3").Value

    Sheet2.Range("Table6").Cells(MatchedRow, 5).Value = Sal
      'Write the calculated Sal back

    MsgBox " remaining: " & Sal
End Sub
```